# Time Series Accuracy with R

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I have the following time series

```
 Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
```

2016 0,0,0,606,662,104,453,642,636,666,619,686

2017 732,693,736,612,492,85,616,798,847,893,821,800

following this tutorial 
https://rpubs.com/RatherBit/90267

i splitted to train and test as follows

```
sr = window(series, start=c(2016,4), end=c(2017,8))
ser = window(series, start=c(2017,9), end=c(2017,12))
trainData <- sr    
testData <- ser
```

and by using aut arima

```
arimaMod <- auto.arima(trainData, stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE)
arimaMod.Fr <-forecast(arimaMod,h=4)
accuracy(arimaMod.Fr,testData)   


                ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE
Training set 7.356697e-14 194.0333 138.9204 -53.74467 73.62606
Test set     2.615441e+02 263.8371 261.5441  31.01124 31.01124
```

the accuracy is bad as i think
could you please help me to improve the accuracy

Answer (score 1):

Your data has very weak autocorrelation and is - *in theory* - not eligible for a time series approach.

```
yt = c(0,0,0,606,662,104,453,642,636,666,619,686,732,693,736,612,492,85,616,798,847,893,821,800)
yt = ts(yt, start = c(2016), frequency = 12)
plot(yt)
Acf(yt)
Box.test(x = yt, type = "Ljung-Box", lag = 2)$p.value
```

The Ljung-Box test of autocorrelation here will seem to be significant (p-value < 0.05), however, if you remove the first three zeros from your series (which are arguably statistical outliers here) then the overall autocorrelation will stop being significant.

As a result, the tools from the forecast package will fail to fit your series:

```
plot(forecast(ets(yt)))
plot(forecast(auto.arima(yt)))
```

However, I found that with this package [here](https://github.com/snarf-snarf/karma) (you need to follow the installation instructions first), you can train and test your series (90%-10% split) with a simple seasonal model to get an out-of-sample MAPE of 8.58%:

```
kfit = auto.karma(yt, method = "local-descent", test_type="percentage", test_pct=10, max_sdiff = T)
karma.cv(kfit)
```

As well as make a decent prediction:

```
plot(forecast(kfit, h=12))
```